# Cassandra Celery python timeout happens on raw query execution using django db connection execute

Tags: python, django, cassandra, celery, cqlengine

My celery is configured for the Cassandra session like this:

```
def cassandra_init(*args, **kwargs):
    """ Initialize a clean Cassandra connection. """
    if cql_cluster is not None:
        cql_cluster.shutdown()
    if cql_session is not None:
        cql_session.shutdown()
    connection.setup([settings.DATABASES["default"]["HOST"],], settings.DATABASES["default"]["NAME"])

# Initialize worker context (only standard tasks)
worker_process_init.connect(cassandra_init)
```

When I am executing a raw cassandra query, timeout happens,

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
total_ap = cursor.execute(
        "SELECT cpu_info  FROM ap_live_stats;")
```

It works well all over in my django project but not inside the celery tasks.

Error:

```
[2018-05-09 18:50:21,576: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-5] Task apps.statistic.tasks.ap_hourly_data_migrator[77a596d4-61a2-43f4-8580-6abc6e9b5866] raised unexpected: OperationTimedOut("errors={'192.168.98.65': 'Client request timeout. See Session.execute[_async](timeout)'}, last_host=192.168.98.65",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vkchlt0079/virtuals/wlc-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 374, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vkchlt0079/virtuals/wlc-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 629, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vkchlt0079/projects/wlcd/src/web_gui/backend/django/wlcd/apps/statistic/tasks.py", line 59, in ap_hourly_data_migrator
    "SELECT cpu_info  FROM ap_live_stats;")
  File "/home/vkchlt0079/virtuals/wlc-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_cassandra_engine/utils.py", line 47, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/home/vkchlt0079/virtuals/wlc-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_cassandra_engine/connection.py", line 12, in execute
    return self.connection.execute(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vkchlt0079/virtuals/wlc-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_cassandra_engine/connection.py", line 86, in execute
    self.session.set_keyspace(self.keyspace)
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 2448, in cassandra.cluster.Session.set_keyspace (cassandra/cluster.c:48048)
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 2030, in cassandra.cluster.Session.execute (cassandra/cluster.c:38536)
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 3844, in cassandra.cluster.ResponseFuture.result (cassandra/cluster.c:80834)
cassandra.OperationTimedOut: errors={'192.168.98.65': 'Client request timeout. See Session.execute[_async](timeout)'}, last_host=192.168.98.65
```

Tried to increase the timeout, but not working and not sure, where it is to be included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# project/tasks.py
from celery.signals import worker_init
from django.db import connection

@worker_process_init.connect
def connect_db(**kwargs):
    connection.reconnect()
```

This will initiate the db connection required via Django Cassandra engine. [Reference](https://r4fek.github.io/django-cassandra-engine/faq/)